# Tab order in tab control with nested dialogs (WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT)

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

In a Win32 API C++ project, I have a dialog with a tab control (3 tabs) and 3 dialogs that are children of the tab control.  I load the main dialog with tab control using DialogBoxParam, and the child dialogs from resources with CreateDialogParam.  The main dialog appears with the child dialogs.  Clicking the tabs shows/hides the correct child dialog, everything working fine.

After searching around about tab orders I found the `WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT` style to set on the tab control to get tabbing working into the child dialog windows.  This works great, except for one problem:  The tab control itself never gets focus, so I can't tab to the tab control to change to a different tab with the keyboard.  Keyboard focus goes through the child dialog, to the buttons on the main dialog, then directly back to the child dialog, and never stops on the tab control itself, so I have to click on the tab control to change tabs.  It's driving me crazy.  Any suggestions?

Update:  I managed to work around the problem by forgetting about `WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT` completely, and making the child dialogs siblings of the tab control.  Only side effect seems to be more flashing of controls during a repaint, but would still like an answer, since making the child dialogs children of the tab seems cleaner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its not cleaner. The recommended way to create tabbed dialogs is to make the tab pages children of the dialog. The tab control simply controls which of the pages is visible, but is not their parent.

This is especially important when you might try to get XP themeing working on the dialog.

`WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT` is a style intended to be set on the actual 'tab' dialogs.

I presume you have set `WS_TABSTOP` on the tab control itself? I imagine that `WS_TABSTOP` and `WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT` conflict when simultaneously set as they tell the dialog manager to do two entirely different and conflicting - things when the tab cycle reaches the control.

Lastly, I cannot see any reason at all that flickering should increase because the dialog pages are children of the dialog rather than the tab control.

Comment: Works for me.  Too many samples on the net of making the dialogs children of the tab control, and MS doesn't make it clear in the docs.  I've since enabled the xp tab theme, and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can't AFAIK because tabbing cycles through the child controls of a dialog by design. Best you could do is preprocess the tab keydown event and if its after the focus is on the last control in the dialog, focus the tab page and discard the event. Not cleaner than the solution you already have it seems to me.

Comment: Seems the DialogProc doesn't get a chance to handle the Tab key, and I don't want to write my own message loop just to fix this.   So I've decided to just leave the solution I have and moved on.  I'm surprised I couldn't find anyone else with the same problem online though.  Everyone says to use WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT, which then produces this new problem.