# Who should be the parent of a tab control child dialog?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dialog, tabcontrol

According to some [sources](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1544082/15025873), a tab child dialog should be the child of the actual main dialog window, not the tab control itself.  I think some of the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/create-a-tab-control-in-the-main-window) suggest the opposite, namely this function example:

```
// Creates a child window (a static control) to occupy the tab control's 
//   display area. 
// Returns the handle to the static control. 
// hwndTab - handle of the tab control. 
// 
HWND DoCreateDisplayWindow(HWND hwndTab) 
{ 
    HWND hwndStatic = CreateWindow(WC_STATIC, L"", 
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER, 
        100, 100, 100, 100,        // Position and dimensions; example only.
        hwndTab, NULL, g_hInst,    // g_hInst is the global instance handle
        NULL); 
    return hwndStatic; 
}
```

So is there a definitive view on this?  I checked Petzold, by the way, but didn't locate anything on the subject.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: [How should I create controls on my dialog box that has a tab control?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20191015-00/?p=102996). Teaser: *"You’d be tempted to create the content of the tab control’s display area as children of the tab control, but that’s the wrong thing to do."*

Comment: Thank you.  Yeah, I figured I was overlooking something by Raymond.  That's my bad.