# What window styles to use to match property sheet behavior?

Tags: winapi

I am attempting to write a program that will have a non-modal dialog that otherwise behaves much like a classic property sheet. That is, it will have a tab control and each tab will show a non-modal child dialog as the tab contents.

Right now I am having problems with how the tab key is handled.

Each child dialog resource currently specifies the DS_CONTROL, WS_TABSTOP, WS_CHILD and WS_VISIBLE styles and is created with the tab control as the parent window. If I create the tab control with the WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT extended style then the child dialog's controls are correctly part of the parent dialog's tab key order but the tab control itself is skipped. If I do not specify WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT then the tab control is correctly part of the parent's tab key order but the child dialog controls are not.

I have also tried giving the child dialog resources the WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT extended style but this makes no difference.

Is there some combination of window styles I have overlooked?

I have also considered achieving this through sub-classing of the tab control but that seems like a very heavy solution if window styles will do.

Comment: why don't you open spy++ to find the styles of what you want?

Comment: Because it hadn't occurred to me. Turns out it's the making the child dialog child to the tab control that really messes things up. Evidently the dialog class only looks at direct children for having the DS_CONTROL style. Might post an own-answer to this once I get everything ironed out.

Comment: *"each tab will show a non-modal child dialog"* - That reads wrong. If the parent dialog is modeless, why do the tab children need to be modeless as well? What's with making the children *extra* modeless? They are modeless already by virtue of the parent being modeless.

Comment: @IInspectable: I was simply trying to emphasize that I am using CreateDialog rather than DialogBox to create the child windows, in an attempt to be as precise as possible in describing what I am doing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67200361/who-should-be-the-parent-of-a-tab-control-child-dialog

Comment: Does the thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34164272/add-controls-to-specific-tab-page-in-tabcontrol-in-c-win32 work for you?

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments the needed styles are to give the child dialogs the DS_CONTROL style while making them children of the parent dialog rather than directly of the tab control.

It is then a matter of hiding the old dialog while handling TCN_SELCHANGING and showing the new dialog during TCN_SELCHANGE.  It was also necessary to update the size/position of the child dialog, along with the z-order (making the newly selected pane the direct follower of the tab control), in the TCN_SELCHANGE handler.